# Recreation of MySQL DB using "mysql mydb < mydb.sql" is really slow when the table has tens of millions of records. How to improve it?

Tags: mysql, database-restore, database-backups

It seems that a MySQL database that has a table with tens of millions of records will get a big `INSERT INTO` statement when the following

```
mysqldump some_db > some_db.sql
```

is done to back up the database.  (is it 1 insert statement that handles **all** the records?)

So when reconstructing the DB using

```
mysql some_db < some_db.sql
```

then the CPU is hardly busy (about 1.8% usage by the mysql process... I don't see a mysqld either?) and also the hard disk doesn't seem to be too busy...

Last time, the whole restore process took 5 hours.  Is there a way to make it faster?  Such as, when doing `mysqldump`, can it break the `INSERT` statement into shorter ones, so that the `mysql` doesn't need to parse the line so hard when restoring the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anything is using time, it will be mysqld, that's what actually does all of the work.  If you're connecting to a remote mysql server then mysqld will be on that machine, not your local one.

The most direct way to speed it up would be to remove all keys and indexes from the table and then create them once the data is loaded.  Keeping everything updated across that many inserts can be very taxing on a server, and will probably cause you to end up with fragmented indexes anyways.  You can expect the index creation at the end of the inserts to take a while, but it won't be as bad as keeping them all up to date as the inserts are taking place.

A better solution would be to stop using mysqldump for that table and switch to using `LOAD DATA INFILE` (with the matching `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` for creating the dump).

Your absolute best bet would be to just copy the database files instead of trying to do a backup and restore.  I think this still only works with MyISAM databases and not InnoDB, but someone else can correct me if things have changed recently.

Comment: Copying the files: Only MyISAM, and a lock on the table when copying (`mysqlhotcopy` comes to mind).

Comment: it is creating the DB on the local hard drive, so i think the mysqld should be on the local machine, but for some reason, when I do a "ps -a" or if i look at the Activities Monitor on a Mac with Snow Leopard, I only see the mysql process but not the mysqld one.

Comment: mysqld usually runs as the user mysql.  I don't know enough about the osx ps command line to tell you what switches to use, but you need to view all processes by all users to find it.